# UITextView not displaying full text on scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitextview

I have a UITextView that is added as a subview to main view of UIViewController. The textView aligns with safeArea on all four edges. When the view controller is pushed over UINavigationController, the text view gets truncated sometimes at the bottom when I scroll. Rotating the device and back shows full text. Is there any configuration that I am missing that needs to be added to UITextView in Storyboard?

Comment: Check your textview constraint again make sure its right.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a code with your textView initializing.

Try to add this to your ViewController

```swift
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    myScroll.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to get your exact senario, But you can check by giving Height & Width constraint's constant values at run time for Protrait & landscape modes (use Orientation delegate methods)